# AVKit trim h264 - frame accurcy

Tags: cocoa, qtkit

I just found the possibility, to edit mp4-movies with the AVKit-Framework. I'm trying to cut my h264-videos between two keyframes. Is this possible with the AVKit-Framework without reencoding the complete stream? (like "smart-rendering"). It seems to work, but I really can't believe, that this really works this simple!

Answer (score 0):

Oh... I experimented a little bit and I found out, that the output video is perfectly played by the Quicktime-Player, but not in the VLC. It seems that the trim-process keeps the complete group of pictures (GOP) between two keyframes, but creates a marker in the file to tell the video player: "Play from this part and ignore the other frames". So perfect for playing files in iTunes or Quicktime, not good for playing them in VLC etc. :(

Comment: yeah that doesn't surprise me... you would have to transcode the hole video with existing tools to make that work I would suspect... although theoretically you could make a tool to make an arbitrary frame an IFrame and just encode that first GOP

Comment: Yes, but I don't think this is possible with the AVKit framework. Maybe the ffmpeg-libraries can do this...